# What are "correlations"?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, many-body

When working with realistic two-body hamiltonians, a direct diagonalization is almost always imposible. Thus one usually takes a procedure which yields an approximate solution. A well known approach of this kind is the Hartree-Fock method, which is based on finding an optimal linear combination of Slater determinants. When reading literature treating this topic, authors say that Hartree Fock ground states do not include as many "pairing correlations" as possible, and thus the Hartree-Fock-Bogolyubov method is proposed by introducing a pairing field which accounts for additional pairing correlations.

But, what are correlations? Are more correlations apart from that responsible of pairing?

Answer (score 1):

The Hartree-Fock method treats the interaction between particles in a mean-field approximation. So the potential felt by particle *i* is given by the average over the wave functions of all the other particles. However - speaking semi-classically - you could imagine that particle *j* has a position as a function of time, and when it's on the "left" side of the nucleus, the potential on particle *i* is more attractive on the left, while when *j* is one the "right" side, the potential on *i* is more attractive to the right. Thus you could expect that particles *i* and *j* have a tendency to be found close together (ie their positions are correlated). This tendency gets washed out in the mean-field approximation.
A less hand-waving explanation would involve expectation values of a two-particle wave function compared to the product of one-particle expectation values.